# How to get rid off only certain zeros formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok so I had a nice formula until a problem came along. Basically I needed to get rid off a zeros in the middle of a 10 characters String/Range i.e AB**0000**5879 to do that I have used formula SUBSTITUTE(NameRange,"0","") which gave me nice AB5879 solution. Sometimes the number at the end would only be 3 digit long AB**00000**975 so my formula would give me AB975 All great until I stumble a problem. Some of the strings came in a form of i.e. AB00004020 So my formula extracted every zero leaving me with AB42. Is there a way to extract only first four zeros in a middle an always keep the number at the and? so the last scenario would look like AB4020. Thanks in advance

SUBSTITUTE(NameRange,"0",""))

Comment: Is your string always start with two letters such as `AB`?

Comment: Hi Terry String always starts with two letters but it can be vary i.e. AB,  AZ, AC, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have two characters at the start and then some zeros and then some numbers, all of which you want to keep, this should work

```
=LEFT(A1,2) & VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2))
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT #2**

If your string always starts with two letters such as `AB` following by a random number of zeros and then a number string that you want to keep, try

```
=LEFT(A1,2)&RIGHT(A1,11-AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($3:$10)/(--MID(A1,ROW($3:$10),1)>0),1))
```

Replace `A1` with your actual case.

[image: Solution2]

Comment: Hi Terry String always starts with two letters but I cant tell what they will be like. any suggestions on this?

Comment: @accurist I have updated my answer using **LEFT** to find the first two letters, but I know there is some flaw of my solution and I think SJR has provided a better one.

Comment: Rather than hardcoding the 10 do you need LEN? Can't get my head round it so not sure.

Comment: @SJR never mind, the LOOKUP function will fail if the string is `AB01000002` or `AB00120034` as the position of `02` and `03` will be returned by the LOOKUP function rather than the position of `01` in both cases. I have updated another solution that should work in all scenario but it looks silly comparing to yours which is far more simple and straight forward. Good job :)